# ReactJS: wrong elements position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to place 3 elements in one row:

1. Label "Filter logs"
2. Input field
3. Select dropdown

I'm trying to use bootstrap but it doesn't work properly: 
[image]

I'm trying to position them with the `col-md` class:

```
<div className="search-audit-logs col-12">

  <h3 className="col-md-2" margin="normal">Filter logs:</h3>

  <TextField
    id="auditLogSearch"
    className="col-md-5"
    label="Search item"
    type="search"
    margin="normal"
    value={this.state.query}
    onChange={(event) => 
    this.setState({ query: event.target.value })
    }
  />

  <FormControl 
    className="col-md-5"
    margin="normal"  
  >
    ....
  </FormControl>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong? In total, there are 12 columns so everything should work.

Comment: can you share it via jsfiddle or codepen or sandbox?

Answer (score 4):

You need a wrapper with class `row` and the use `col-*`

```
<div className="row search-audit-logs" >
   <div className="col-md-4">

   </div>
   <div className="col-md-4">

   </div>
   <div className="col-md-4">

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put or nest the col-md-* inside col-12. 
The columns (col-md-* or col-sm-* or col-*) should be nested inside a div with classname="row".

That's how Bootstrap works.

Also don't use the className="col-*" on inline elements like h3, TextField, etc. Use those classes with container elements like div, section, header, footer, main, etc.

Hope this clarifies it for you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS grid class example keeps rows and columns. Example at

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid

Style

```
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Also, this example gets away from the td tr code. Column 
and row code gets mangled on screen sizes you don’t 
code for or if you don’t test for different screen sizes.